# import Youtube Android player ID using gradle dependencies

Tags: android-youtube-api

Is there any way we can import(use) Youtube Android Player API by just mentioning dependencies in build.gradle file?

Although there exists a method to download and import he library as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup). But I want to use it using gradle dependencies.